# How to remove scrolling delay on website?

Tags: html, css, xml

On my blogger website I have been deciding on what template I want to use and I found the one I like, but for some reason with the particular template that I picked, there is a delay when scrolling on the website.

www.lifeof56.com

Is there a way to make scrolling automatic or instant? I appreciate the help!

Comment: please include any attempts you've made to solve this problem

Comment: I don't know what code to use to even attempt to solve the problem. Is it the scrollbar? is it overflow? is it scroll speed?

Comment: Disable/remove the code for `jquery.nicescroll`, or alter its configuration.

Comment: Thank you! Removing the code did the job!